# How do I perform this complex integration?

Tags: complex-systems

Evaluate the complex integration $(z^2 + 3z)$ wrt $z$ along the circle $|z| = 2$, from $(2,0)$ to $(0,2)$ in a counterclockwise direction.

As far as I understand, this can be solved by taking $x = 2 \cos \theta$,  $y = 2 \sin \theta$, and then integrating wrt $\theta$ from $0$ to $π/2$.

But on making these substitutions, the integration becomes quite lengthy and clumsy.
Is there any other way to solve this, which I might be missing right now?

Comment: Try a contour integral, using (0,0) to (2,0) and (0,2) to (0,0) as additional sides. and note that the contour integral has no poles.

Answer (score 2):

On your circle, $z=2e^{it}$, $0\leq t\leq\pi/2$. Then your integral is (never forget to include the change of variable, $dz=2ie^{it}\,dt$)
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2} ((2e^{it})^2+6e^{it})\,2ie^{it}\,dt
&=2i\int_0^{\pi/2}(4e^{3it}+6e^{2it})\,dt
=2i\left[ \left.\frac{4e^{3it}}{3i}+\frac{3e^{2it}}{i}\right|_0^{\pi/2}\right]\\ \ \\
&=-\frac {8i}3-6-\frac83-6=-\frac {44}3-\frac {8i}3.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes. Now I get it. Instead of writing z as x + iy, I should write it in the r e^it form, which makes the task simpler.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You lost a factor of $e^{it}$ going between the two integral expressions.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for noticing!

Comment: +1, but still some errors. The final answer should be
$$-\frac{44}{3}-\frac{8}{3}i$$

Comment: Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. This is the final answer given in my book. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int _{2}^{2i}  z^2+3z dz =(1/3)z^3 +(3/2) z^2 |_2^{2i} = (-44/3)-(8/3)i$$

Comment: This is easy !  I had thought of this earlier, but what confused me was the circle given in question.

Comment: @Jasmine: This is because of "The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus".

Comment: @epimorphic: I do agree that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus cannot be applied to complex contour integrals but its the most efficient way to get the result provided the domain is simply connected and the function is analytic on the domain

Comment: @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani: Your integrand should be $z^2+3z$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Oops, you're right, I really need to review my complex analysis... \*slinks back into corner\*

Comment: @quasi Thanks for the comment. I fixed my error.

Comment: @epimorphic: A kind suggestion: You may leave your comments undeleted so that it may help people with similar doubts to correct their arguments.